# How to implement OnClickListener of ListView items for good performance (avoiding slow scrolling)

Tags: android-listview

I've been reading about [ViewHolder Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) and it's effects on `ListView` scrolling performance lately.

For a smooth scrolling, fast `ListView` should i *avoid using* `OnClickListener` registerations inside *adapter* `getView()` method such as:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(mResourceId, null);

        holder.btn1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        holder.img1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img1);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else { holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); }

    final Items item = getItem(position);

    holder.btn1.setText(item.btnText);
    holder.img1.setBackgroundResource(item.imgSource);

    holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { /* .. my code block USING POSITION ARG .. */ }
    }

    holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { /* .. My Code Block USING POSITION ARG .. */ }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

If so, is registering a `OnItemClickListener` to `ListView` instance as following sample does a good practice:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btn1)
        {
            // my code block USING POSITION ARG     
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.img1)
        {
            // my code block USING POSITION ARG                         
        }                   
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use a *Wrapper* to access to your `View` and to define your `OnClickListener` earlier (and *outside the adapter* for a better usability).

The following sample show how to handle 2 *clickable* `View` on one single item of the `ListView` with good performance:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Item> items;
    private ItemWrapper wrapper = null;
    private OnClickListener onMyItemClickListener1;
    private OnClickListener onMyItemClickListener2;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items, OnClickListener onMyItemClickListener1, OnClickListener onMyItemClickListener2) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
        this.onMyItemClickListener1 = onMyItemClickListener1;
        this.onMyItemClickListener2 = onMyItemClickListener2;
    }        

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item, null);
            wrapper = new ItemWrapper(row);
            row.setTag(wrapper);
        } else {
            wrapper = (ItemWrapper)row.getTag();
        }

        Item item = getItem(position);
        wrapper.getClickView1().setOnClickListener(onMyItemClickListener1);
        wrapper.getClickView2().setOnClickListener(onMyItemClickListener2);
        return(row);
    }        
}

public class ItemWrapper {
    private View baseView;
    private View clickView1;
    private View clickView2;

    public ItemWrapper(View baseView) {
        this.baseView = baseView;
    } 

    public View getClickView1() {
        if ( clickView1 == null) {
            clickView1 = (View)baseView.findViewById(R.id.clickView1);
        }

        return(clickView1);
    }  

    public View getClickView2() {
        if ( clickView2 == null) {
            clickView2 = (View)baseView.findViewById(R.id.clickView2);
        }

        return(clickView2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing sample. Can you please add description

Comment: I corrected the naming (bad copy/paste :/)
Also you should use `ListView.OnItemClickListener()` but sometimes, espacially when you have more than one clickable element you have to use multiple `OnClickListener`. Just modify the code to get what you want, as many time you want.